# Azure Service Bus Subscription Filter on message body

Tags: azure, filter, azureservicebus, subscription

I would like to create a subscription based on the content of a Message. Is this possible?
I am trying to get away from having to add a custom property.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible. Subscriptions can only filter based on standard (system) and custom (user) properties. If you have the data in the body/payload that needs to participate in filtering, you will need to promote it to the header.

Comment: Is there any performance or cost implication adding more custom headers? Also is it a good practice to add a custom header like EventType and then have subscription filtered by the EventType ?

Comment: Performance impact to your application (that adds a custom header) and the client (to convert `Message` into AMQP message) are insignificant. Unless you promote so that it takes up to 64KB of headers and will start taking a tall. When it comes to a business need to filter on a value coming from a message body, don't think there's another option. And if you're concerned about performance degradation in this case, you might need to re-evaluate use of the service you've selected. For an enterprise messaging I would assume this is not a significant impact compared to the value it provides.