# Service bus filtering the message based on content

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

In Service Bus there is no option to filter messages based on content unlike event grid subscriptions. So I have a scenario where I get the message in a queue and I need forward it to a topic subscription and filter messages based on few nodes in the body. To achieve this one of the option is to read messages from queue using a Azure function and promote the required node as user properties and sending message to topic. But this requires processing of each message in a function. Is there any better mechanism to handle this scenario with better performance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no direct method to filter messages based on content whatever method you are using is the best one. Because subscriptions can only filter based on the standard system and custom properties. You can try promoting the content to header.

for complete information, you can go ahead with this [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52306317), [Subscription filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-filter-examples), and [topic filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters).